# Get base node included in results with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am trying to get the permissions on a folder structure for a specific user. I first get a list of folders then loop over then getting the permissions on each where the user is in the permission list path. eg.

```
start n = node(folderID) match n<-[r:SECURITY]-x, x<-[v:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP*]-b where b.Name = "user1" return n,r.Comment;

start n = node(3911) match n<-[r:SECURITY]-x, b-[v:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP*]-x where b.Name = "user1" return x, r.Comment;
```

The problem is it doesn't include the user1 relationship in the results. 
Is there a way to include this in the query? (not as a separate column). Tree structure looks like: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/examples-acl-structures-in-graphs.html

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly which relatinships of the user1 you would like to include? it's the relationship of "IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP", or "SECURITY" or "PRINCIPAL", or perhaps all of them?

Comment: In the relationship diagram user1 has a SECURITY relationship with user1 home. I want to include that SECURITY relationship. eg. on folder(user1 home) get all SECURITY relationships that are part of user1s IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP tree.

Comment: Understood. if you need to return all "SECURITY" relationship in a single column, the easy way is to just use the "UNION" clause, the first query returns the "SECURITY" relationships for the x as what your query does, the second query just returns the "SECURITY" relationship for the "user1", then combine the two with "UNION".

Comment: You also can do a gist.neo4j.org to illustrate this.